# How to get Integration Test Results with additional output like number of: total tests, failed tests etc in Sonarqube?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, integration-testing, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner

How to get Integration Test Results with additional output like number of: total tests, failed tests etc in Sonarqube?

My setup has jenkins integrated to sonarqube and I'm looking to get sonarqube display, the following results:

1. Number of Tests
2. Number of Tests Passed
3. Number of Test Failed
4. Number of Test Skipped
5. Total Execution time

As of now the **Integration Test Results widget** gives me only Coverage Results Output.

Answer (score 0):

if you have tests unit and/or It, they sould be 'upload' on your sonarqube project dashboard. ( as the same way you should see then on your jenkins project dashboard )

Then, in 'Mesures' menu, at 'coverage' tab, there is a lots of displayed informations like nb test in failure, nb tests success, total exec time, nb tests skipped ...